# Are there any hooks for Better Exposed Filters?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm trying to modify the output of "Better Exposed Filters". When displaying the sort options as links, the module will always output links for sorting ascending **and** descending. I'd like to remove the descending option for each sorting criteria.

I did an ugly hack in better_exposed_filters.theme, which resides right in the module's directory, like this:

```
function theme_select_as_links($vars) {

    //function does its stuff

    foreach ($element_set as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, " DESC")) {
            continue;
        }
        //foreach loop does its stuff

    }
}
```

While this works just fine it's obviously done in the wrong place. The next update would certainly break it. Is there a hook for "Better Exposed Filters" I could use in my template file instead?

Answer (score 2):

You are pratically there!

The way that Drupal works is that any function that starts with theme_blah_blah can be copied and placed directly into your template.php of your custom theme. Then you change the actual call from theme_ to yourcustomthemename_

So in this case you have `function theme_select_as_links($vars) {` which you would change to `function myawesometheme_select_as_links($vars)`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [Erik Web - Hook definition](http://www.erikwebb.net/blog/drupal-design-patterns/hooks/) and have a search above the hook definition implementation within the module. This way you can find out each hook that can be used.
I would go for: **module_invoke_all, module_implements, drupal_alter, module_invoke**